# How can I declare a variable without initiate it in ANGULAR? -Strict mode problem

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I try to declare a new object type or a simple string variable but I get an error

```
this_is_variable:string;
recipe : Recipe;
```

the errors:

> Property 'recipe' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

> Property 'this_is_variable' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

In the above example **Recipe** is a class which I have import it

```
export class Recipe{
public name:string;
public description : string;
public imagePath: string;
constructor(name:string="none", desc:string="none" , imagePath:string="none"){
    this.name= name;
    this.description=desc;
    this.imagePath= imagePath;


}

}
```

Comment: Try `varName?: type` declaration ;)

Comment: @YongShun it does , thank you. but I still have the variable underlined with red in VS code, is there anything I can do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reported error is from typescript compiler. Set the property `strictPropertyInitialization` to `false` in `tsconfig.json` file of Angular app solution to avoid this compiler error.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... rest
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
}
```